# Rear view controller keeps changing widths

Tags: swift, swrevealviewcontroller

So I would like my rear view to have a width of 260.0 (which I believe is the default), but I'm having this weird problem where the first time the rear view is shown it's at the correct width, but every time after that is a smaller width, like so: first time[image: First time]

second time[image: Second time]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: why rear view default width 260? Which iphone model are you using? iphone 5 dimensions are 320x568 points

Comment: Are you setting the `rearViewRevealWidth` anywhere in your code? If yes, where and please add some more code and details. Thanks.

Comment: I don't set `rearViewRevealWidth` anywhere in my code, but I did go into `SWRevealViewController.m` and changed `_rearViewRevealOverdraw` from `60.0f` to `0.0f` because I didn't want the right side to be covered up.

Comment: @TheBeanstalk can you please undo that and try to set the rear view reveal width once in your code and see if that works? Thanks